# Is it possible to remove a file from git commit history in a protected branch?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed a private file to a protected branch and already deleted it but I can't clear it from my history. Because the branch is protected by someone that isn't me, I can't force push. I have tried using BFG repo-cleaner. Should I accept this commit will be in my history permanently?

Comment: That "someone that isn't you" has the answer. This is not a technical issue per se, you need to discuss workflow with them.

Comment: Hi! A little bit of common advice, but if this "private file" contained any passwords/tokens, you should change/revoke them ASAP. Also, I believe that the answear from @Serg sums it up really well :)

Comment: Also note that "repo-cleaner" and similar tools also require force-pushes to modify existing branches, so they don't help any more here than manually removing the commit with something like interactive rebase.

Comment: Thanks everyone for this helpful information. My concern isn't too grand, but it contains a deadname and I would have preferred my TA's to not accidentally stumble across it. I turned in the commit ID of my final commit which is clean, so hopefully they don't try to go back into my history for any reason. Once the class is over, the whole repo gets deleted so it won't be a concern from there.

Comment: If keeping information in the commit hidden from the actual administrators of the repo, then keeping silent and hoping for the best might just be your best bet indeed. And if your TAs are anything like the ones I interacted with they don't usually have spare time to dig into the history if there's no explicit reason.

Answer (score 2):

Despite non-fast forward pushes is forbidden, it is possible that you still have permissions to remove the whole branch from a remote repository. So, you can remove the branch and then push a new brunch with the same name but without problematic commits.

If branch removal is also forbidden, you can't do anything yourself and the only way is to contact someone who have appropriate permissions to enable non-fast forward pushes or remove branch (e.g. repository owner/admin/etc)

Comment: Note that removing the branch is a good first step, but it often leaves the commit still reachable until the remote git repository does a GC (which one usually can't control). So if  a security risk is to be avoided, you'll **have** to contact an administrator of that remote repository.